# Ubuntu 12.10 won't boot after install

Tags: installation, 12.10

I recently wiped my hard disk and tried to install ubuntu 12.10 but after a sucessful install from the USB,I booted from the HD and when I do I get a purple screen saying ubuntu and a loading animation but that's all it does,it keeps loading and loading an I can't get to the login screen...I'm used ext2 as the /boot and btrfs as /..I don't know if that would affect this but I did it because it kept failing to create a ext4 partition....please help!

Comment: Check the boot options, you might need to set acpi=off or something similar. Happened to me when I updated to 12.04.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your hardware please, could be a driver issue. Your video card might not be working properly. Also try what @Dialogos suggested

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that strangely worked for me in the past is:

When viewing the purple ubuntu screen, wait like 1 minute then press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. Login with yer account and type `sudo restart lightdm`. Might work for you as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login through the console, as Dialogos suggests, I would also plug it in to a network connection and run the updates:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

As I have seen this type of behaviour before, and generally there is an update that fixes it.

Also, Ubuntu 12.10 support ends in April 2014.
  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases